# Seeking Recommendations for a More Powerful Desk Light

Tags: light, grow-lamp, venus-fly-trap

I'm looking for a new grow light for my plants. The current lamp I have is too short in width, so it doesn't cover all the plants evenly. While it provides up to 20k lux at the center and based on a conversion factor of 50-70 lux per 1 µmol/m²/s of PAR, this translates to about 286-400 µmol/m²/s. . However, the light intensity drops to around 5k lux at the ends of the pots.

I'm not interested in purple/blue grow lights or single bulbs like SANSI. I'd prefer a longer and more powerful lamp that's similar to my current setup. Here's a photo for reference:
https://imgur.com/a/IF4xXvR
[image: Two carnivorous plants under a small grow light]

[image: The same grow light with a light meter reading 22,450 LUX]

Do you have any recommendations for a longer and stronger grow light that would suit my needs?